# What is the purpose of R2 in this discrete voltage regulator circuit?

Tags: transistors, voltage-regulator

I understand the general working of the circuit - R1 biases Q1, Q2 acts as an error amplifier closing Q1 just enough to get 1.4V at it's base. What is the puropse of R2?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f020Wv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: @jippie thanks! will try it tomorrow on the breadboard :)

Comment: @jippie: I think you're a bit confused about how R3 works. When the wiper is at the top, Vout is at its minimum value (1.4V). As you turn R3 down, Vout rises until it equals Vin.

Comment: @DaveTweed you are right, that's what happens when I stay up past bed time. I'll remove that comment.

Comment: @DaveTweed you didn't however bring me from my thought that with D1 in series with R3 to GND will give smooth control at the lower end of R3.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

R2 simply makes sure that there's a certain amount of current flowing through Q1 even if no external load is attached to the circuit. This is called a "minimum load".

It also makes sure that a certain amount of current is flowing through D1, which makes its forward voltage drop have a more stable value, improving the regulation of the circuit overall.

Note that as long as R1 = R2, the current through D1 is independent of the actual value of Vout; it only depends on Vin and the resistor value. The current flowing through R1 is (Vin – Vout – Vbe) / R1. The current flowing through R2 is (Vout – Vf) / R2. If you add these together, the Vout terms cancel, leaving (Vin – Vbe – Vf) / R1.

The only current through these two resistors that doesn't flow through the diode is the base current of Q1, which means that the diode current slightly depends on the amount of current being drawn by the load, depending on the actual gain (current transfer ratio) of Q1. For high loads, this would be a good place for a Darlington.

Comment: R3 already guarantees some minimum load, so I suspect your second point is the main reason.

Comment: Have a question.  Wouldn't the current flowing through R1 be (Vin - Vout + Vbe) / R1? Or is this a straight KVL equation like you have shown. It looks like the voltage at the other end of R1 is going to be Vbe above Q1's emitter voltage.  Just want to make sure I am understanding correctly.

Comment: @mrbean: Yes, that's why you need to subtract Vbe, not add it. The total drop from Vin to Vout is (Vin - Vout). Some of that appears as Vbe, while the rest is the voltage across R1. In other words, Vin - Vout = V(R1) + Vbe. Solving for V(R1) requires subtracting Vbe from both sides to get to the expression I show above.

Comment: @DaveTweed - I'm still confused on how that works.  The drop from Vin to Vout is Vin - Vout.  In terms of the BJT, that is Vc - Ve.  In order for the BJT to turn on the base needs to be a higher voltage than the emitter.  So you need to add Vbe (~0.4 - 0.7 V) to the emitter voltage at node Ve to get the base voltage at node Vb.  Therefore, Vb = Ve + Vbe.  To solve for the voltage across the resistor, Vr1 = Vc - Vb = Vin - Vb = Vin - Ve + Vbe.  If you subtract, you'll have Vbe less than Vout at Vb.  Which is incorrect.

Comment: @DaveTweed I don't believe your equation matches what you're saying.  You said some of Vin - Vout appears as Vbe.  So you would need to add Vbe back in to Vin - Vout to get the base voltage.  Vb is one diode drop or Vbe above Ve.  And Ve = Vout since the pass transistor is an emitter follower.  So Vb = Ve + Vbe = Vout + Vbe.  If we're looking for the voltage across the resistor that would be Vin - Vout + Vbe.  The way your equation is currently written, you would have a resistor in series with a diode in parallel with Vin - Vout.

Comment: @mrbean: If Vb = Ve + Vbe and Vr1 = Vc - Vb (your statements above), then the two equations can be combined to form Vr1 = Vc - (Ve + Vbe), which can also be written as Vr1 = Vc - Ve - Vbe. The minus sign distributes to both terms inside the parentheses. This is basic algebra.

Comment: @DaveTweed I understand what you're saying.  From what I remember the associative property doesn't work for subtraction.  Since the associative property doesn't apply to subtraction, I don't believe the minus sign can be distributed like that.  From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property, _However, many important and interesting operations are **non-associative**; some examples include **subtraction**, exponentiation, and the vector cross product._  Example (6-3)-2 = 1, 6-(3-2) = 5. Note that the results don't equal. This is because the order of operations matters for subtraction.

Comment: Here is an example closer to our actual equation: (6-3)+2=5 and 6-(3+2)=1.  If we distribute the minus sign 6-(3+2) = 6-3-2=1.  This still isn't right because the order of operations is wrong. For our original equation 6-3+2.  The 3 needs to be subtracted from 6 first.  Then the two can be added.

Comment: @mrbean: Substituting "(Ve + Vbe)" for "Vb" has nothing at all to do with associativity. Also, the distribution of a factor of -1 across the two terms of the sum is perfectly valid. $$-1\cdot Vb = -1\cdot(Ve + Vbe) = -1\cdot Ve + -1\cdot Vbe$$ $$-Vb = -(Ve + Vbe) = -Ve - Vbe$$ You're not going to get very far in engineering if you have this much trouble with basic math.

Comment: Are we still talking about the same thing?  If you have a regulator with Vin = 20 V and Vout = 10 V, the base of the pass transistor has to be higher than the emitter in order for the circuit to work.  Vin - Vout + Vbe is the correct equation.  20 - 10 V + 0.7 V = 10.7 V is going to be the base voltage.  If the circuit is a darlington pair. 20 V - 10 V + 1.4 V = 11.4 V is going to be the base voltage.  You realize the equation you wrote has the base voltage lower than the emitter correct?  Try simulating and using your equation.

Comment: Here is a perfect example. 
 https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/84196/what-does-this-component-do-in-this-series-pass-regulator.  Show me how they got 5.71 mA through the 680 Ohm resistor.

Comment: I just realized I'm doing this: 18 V - (12.7 V + 1.4 V) in my head when I look at the circuit.  I'm doing the additon first.  You're doing this 18 V - 12.7 V - 1.4 V.  You do the subtraction first.  We get the same answer.  I'm not sure what the hell I was thinking.  You're right.

Comment: I apparently can't do math.

Comment: How do you look at the circuit?  I see that the base voltage has to be higher than the emitter and in my mind have to add Vbe to Vout first.  I can't picture the circuit doing the subtraction operations.   How do you see that?

Comment: Ok I think I see the loop you're doing.