# Vbe limit in basic series voltage regulator circuit

Tags: voltage-regulator, zener

An ubiquitous series regulator circuit below sometimes used without any capacitors, but more often has a capacitor on the output as well as one on zener.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flpCvh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the answer to the [different question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/84200/187920) with more complex circuit there is a mention of potential overvoltage on BJT base in case of shorted output.

Following the same logic, if large bulk capacitor is added to the output of basic "resistor + zener + NPN" circuit it will create transient short to the ground condition when powered up. So there will be a brief time when Vbe is defined by zener voltage.

In my specific case Vz is 15V, and Vbe(max) is 6V. Should I worry about that?

There are thousands of these circuits on the web and no one mentions Vbe limit. To be fair, most datasheets specify the limit in "open collector" condition, which is not the case here. Maybe this makes all the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If emitter current is ever, for some reason, sourced entirely via the base, which is the only reason the BE junction might be stressed, that current is limited by R1. As long as R1 isn't stupidly small, \$V_{BE}\$ won't exceed the usual 0.7V or so.

Since Q1 collector and base get their current from the same +30V node, the collector will always provide the lion's share of emitter current, by a factor of \$\beta\$, whether the output is short circuited or not.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fL8Znu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The most interesting thing here is that R1 permits base potential to fall, saving the BE junction by preventing \$V_{BE}\$ from ever reaching that maximum of 6V. It can fall to 0.7V or so in the case of the output short circuit. In that condition, base current is capped at:

$$ I_{B(MAX)} = \frac{30V - 0.7V}{R_1} $$

Collector current will also be capped, to around

$$ I_{C(MAX)} = \beta I_{B(MAX)} $$

Your assertion that "there will be a brief time when Vbe is defined by zener voltage" is therefore incorrect, unless R1 is too small.

Comment: I see. What about the Darlington devices with "built-in shunt resistors", like [MJD122](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/c0/55/07/19/ee/bc/43/4e/CD00000829.pdf/files/CD00000829.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000829.pdf)? Will those affect your analysis?

Comment: @Maple No. Those shunt resistors are in parallel with the BE junctions, perhaps bypassing current around them, but R1 still is the main throttle for current *entering* the base.

Answer (score 2):

> Vbe(max) is 6V

Where did that spec come from? The specification in transistor datasheets is for **emitter-base** voltage, i.e. reverse bias on the B-E junction. The spec is Veb(max)=6V, not Vbe(max)! Subtle but a big difference.

If for any reason the output voltage is 6-7V above the Zener voltage, the transistor will be damaged since E-B will break down in reverse, followed by C1 discharging through E-B.

The ubiquitous regulator circuit should at least have reverse B-E protection diode D2, and ideally also reverse C-E protection diode D3:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9L8XC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

D3 protects the transistor when the input gets shorted while C1 is charged.

A C2 is also recommended, since it is multiplied by the gain of the transistor, so C1 can be smaller.

Comment: "The spec is Veb(max)=6V, not Vbe(max)!" a big difference indeed. It seems I've misread the datasheet and was worried for nothing

Comment: @Maple The V(be) spec - if there was one - is much lower, since you'd be driving a lot of current through the B-E junction. At 6V B-E, the junction will be in the process of evaporating :) B-E voltages on high power transistors driven "full-tilt" may reach 1.5V, and that's about as much as I'd ever expect to see across a Silicon BJT B-E junction.

Comment: In normal operation the voltage on C1 is just slightly less than full bus voltage. If bus disconnected, D2 will apply it to zener. Without current limiting provided by R1 would not it burn zener right away?

Answer (score 1):

I think biasing the zener speed up the Q2 response mainly when Q2 Ic has to be decreased (suddenly loaded output) because unloaded zener has too low impedance to discharge Q2 BE fast enough.

Also zener voltage is more predicable if zener is pre-biased, otherwise high Q2 Ic change causes high zener voltage change. With zener 1k2 biasing the zener current change is smaller, i.e. zener voltage reference is more precise.

Comment: Are you saying that an accepted answer in that question is incorrect and resistor in there has nothing to do with protecting Q2 base-emitter junction from overvoltage? In any case, I was asking about much simpler circuit, which may or may not have this problem.