# Maximum voltage applied to the BJT base

Tags: bjt, power-dissipation, base

I have a functional circuit designed for return line reverse protection, and a relevant portion of the circuit is shown below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQNq9Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this circuit, I anticipate that when +28V is connected to the return line, it will turn on Q1, causing point B to be at 0.7V. However, if point A is at 28V, point B would theoretically be 2 * 28V = 56V. Although the transistor (Q1) stabilizes point B to 0.7V, there is still dissipation heat generated that could potentially damage the transistor. According to the [MMBTA06](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/MMBTA05_MMBTA06.pdf) datasheet, the maximum emitter-base voltage is specified as 4.0V, which suggests that Q1 might be at risk of failure. Surprisingly, despite this, Q1 does not blow up. Upon consulting my teacher, he indicated that the use of 0805-sized resistors R3 and R2 may be preventing any issues. But it does not make sense to me. Please advise.

Comment: Your circuit diagram seems to have some errors in it. For example, if the circuit is operated with the correct polarity (0V at "Return" and likely 28V at "INPUT PWR"), D2 is going to blow up.

Comment: What is the ground reference? Is return 0V ground and PWR 28V? If so, the diode and zener will blow up. Also if Q1 turns on, it will blow up the diode. Also Q1 can't turn on if return is 0V. That can't be a functional circuit.

Comment: I'm also a student wanting to learn from this, Can you explain a. when +28 is connected with A, how will B be theoretically 2x28 = 56 V? can you explain the dynamics involved in this?

Comment: @Fedrick, This circuit is designed to deactivate when the polarity of the positive and negative inputs is reversed. When a negative voltage is applied to point A, it turns off Q1, allowing the positive input voltage to be clamped by the zener diode and turning on the FET. However, there is a consensus that this positive voltage may cause D2 to fail. I noted VB=2*28V because there is a voltage divider at point B, where VB equals VA multiplied by (1 + 47.5/47.5).

Comment: @Jonathan S. Can you share your calculation explaining how you determined that D2 will fail? The original design includes a 1M ohm resistor in parallel with D2 and 2*47.5K ohm resistors between D1 and D2, although I did not initially mention them as it was challenging to discern the reason behind their inclusion. I initially thought that Vz=12V would clamp, and there would be no need for concern

Comment: @Justme Can you share your calculation explaining how you determined that D2 will fail? The original design includes a 1M ohm resistor in parallel with D2 and 2*47.5K ohm resistors between D1 and D2, although I did not initially mention them as it was challenging to discern the reason behind their inclusion. I initially thought that Vz=12V would clamp, and there would be no need for concern

Comment: @chami We can't work with simplified circuits. We can't know what you omitted because you thought was not important. The circuit you drew blows up because you can't have 28V over a 12V zener or transistor shorting to ground. Also the ground reference is seemingly unrelated to +28 V supply and return.

Comment: @Justme sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The voltage will not exceed about 0.7V with 28V at point A because the current is limited to 27.3V/47.5kΩ  or less than 0.6mA.

The maximum emitter-base voltage is specified at 4V, you are applying (forward) base-emitter voltage. In other words the data sheet is telling you that -4V base voltage wrt emitter is the limit. This is because of potential reverse breakdown in the base-emitter junction. Most jellybean NPN silicon transistors are rated for -5V. RF transistors, often less.

Can't say as the rest of the circuit makes much sense- the MOSFET is connected as a source follower and diode D1 provides a path to destroy the BJT as well as itself.

Comment: Can you please explain further, the concept of forward base-emitter voltage which you have explained here?

Comment: "Can you also provide guidance on how to calculate protection for the zener D2? Thanks

Comment: Thanks. So, I need to ensure that IB is less than 10mA, right? This is to pass testing when VA is less than 475V?

Comment: There's no specific limit in the datasheet for Ib that I can see, however 10mA is reasonable. The base-emitter junction behaves like a diode- a diode with a very low reverse breakdown.

Answer (score 4):

> maximum **emitter-base** voltage is specified as 4.0V

This is not the same as **base-emitter**. *The order of the words matters*. The first word is the terminal with the higher potential.

You never have a situation where emitter-base voltage goes positive (where the emitter is higher than the base), much less where it would go positive enough to be 4V positive. If you expect large negative transients on the return line then a reverse diode connected from emitter to base will do the job of protecting the B-E junction from reverse breakdown.

The base-emitter voltage is limited by the base junction forward diode drop. It will be well below 1V in your application, but again - that's not specified anywhere, since the B-E junction acts like a nice silicon junction diode.

There's another [question that is based on the same misunderstanding](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/696413/10810). See the answers to it as well.